# How do I diagnose lots of packet lost with a Ubuntu Server over wifi (while Windows gets them all!)

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I have several servers on a local network, mostly Windows 2008, 2012 and an Ubuntu server.

Since about a month I have problems with the Ubuntu Server: if I connect via ssh it hangs after seconds, if I ping it lots of packets are lost:

This tests have been done over wifi, here's pinging the gateway from my workstation:

```
--- 10.39.52.240 ping statistics ---
25 packets transmitted, 25 received, 0% packet loss, time 24036ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.793/4.934/54.950/10.256 ms
```

Here a Windows server:

```
--- 10.39.52.9 ping statistics ---
25 packets transmitted, 25 received, 0% packet loss, time 24042ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.397/2.386/5.093/1.030 ms
```

And here the Ubuntu Server, **with 42% of packets lost**

```
--- 10.39.52.12 ping statistics ---
28 packets transmitted, 16 received, 42% packet loss, time 27073ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.408/5.281/42.693/9.830 ms
```

Pinging **from** the Ubuntu Server to the Windows Server, **cable connection**, is ok:

```
--- 10.39.52.9 ping statistics ---
1255 packets transmitted, 1255 received, 0% packet loss, time 1255013ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.169/0.347/1.227/0.151 ms
```

Pinging **from** the Windows Server to the Ubuntu Server, **cable connection**, is ok:

```
Ping statistics for 10.39.52.12:
    Packets: Sent = 41, Received = 41, Lost = 0
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

So I tried pinging Ubuntu Server from my workstation using **cable connection, everything is ok**:

```
--- 10.39.52.12 ping statistics ---
25 packets transmitted, 25 received, 0% packet loss, time 23999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.201/0.306/0.532/0.058 ms
```

So, why only over wifi to Ubuntu Server? Why not pinging Windows?

**How do I diagnose this?**

Comment: Could it be a hardware issue in the Ubuntu's WiFi adapter?

Comment: Hello, the Ubuntu Server is cabled — it's a VM in our cabled host server actually — my workstation is connected to the network through wifi and it's a OpenSUSE notebook, it might be part of the problem tho...

Comment: You need to troubleshoot the WiFi in the OpenSUSE. Nothing to do with Ubuntu therefore this question is only suitable for [unix.se].

Comment: Install Wireshark and see what it says?

Comment: @MichaelBay: maybe OpenSUSE is involved, certainly Ubuntu Server has its share, being the only in the network causing problem at the moment vs 6 other Windows servers... :( @muru: will it running `wireshark[enter]` give me an answer? ;)